# 100% height of screen div image background fixed then content will come when scroll

Tags: jquery, css

100% height of screen div image background fixed then content will come when scroll.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="main-bg">

 </div>
<div style="height: 400px; background: red;" class="after">

 </div>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-bg{
    background: url(../images/bg-img.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Want to make something like this page scroll : https://www.cognizantadvising.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for parallax scrolling effect!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
body,html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.main-bg{
    background-image: url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/8881b7afcbef4c0dbf9ea77f6169176c.jpg/v1/fill/w_1920,h_1280,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/8881b7afcbef4c0dbf9ea77f6169176c.webp');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top:10em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-bg">
    <div style="height: 600px; background: #CCC;" class="after"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: main-bg 100% height of screen then lot f content to come when scroll

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body{
  background-color:#eee;
  background-image:url(http://imgadd.net/im/7081cb75ab.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.content{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  background:#fff;
  }
  .s{
    color:#fff;
    background:transparent;
    padding:20px; 
    text-align:center;
  }
  .a{background:#eee;}
  .b{background:#fff;}
```

```html
<div class="content s">
    text1
</div>
<div class="content a">
    text2
</div>
<div class="content b">
    text3
</div>
```